# Query all objects based on entity property value?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I have a custom property in my entity:

```
public function getStockSoldPercentage()
{
    return ($this->getStockSold() / $this->getFullStock()) * 100;
}
```

By using this property, I can access the percentage of stock sold out. At the moment I use a query like this

```
$bestellers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CoreBundle:Products')->findAll();
```

and handle the filtering of the objects (all products with a percentage above e.g. 75%) directly in my twig template. So you see, this isn't really good regarding scaling. When I have to query 1000 products each time a user visits the website, is overkill…

I want to build a custom entity repository, something like `findAllBestSellers()` and just query all objects whose `getStockSoldPercentage()` property is higher than 75.

How can I do this?

### EDIT :

`getStockSold()` and `getFullStock()` are not fields, but functions. They look like this:

```
public function getFullStock()
{
    $stock = 0;
    foreach ($this->variants as $variant) {
        $stock += $variant->getStock();
    }
    return $stock;
}

public function getStockSold()
{
    return $this->getFullStock() - $this->getCurrentStock();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In fact, you've applicative logic needs too complex to do it in another way inside your application. You can't simply request your database in SQL to get what you want.

BUT, I advise you to create an sql function which is returning your products and transcript all your logic in it. That will load balance the charge on your applicative server and mysql is far more efficient to do it.

After that, you can call your function by doing :

```
public function findAllBestSellers() {

    $sql = "SELECT PRODUCTS_WITH_STOCK_SOLD_PERCENTAGE() AS products";
    $stmt = $this->dbal->executeQuery($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    return current($stmt->fetch());
}
```

Comment: thanks for this, but it doesn't work in my case. please see my edit!

Comment: Can I see your product entity ? or just : Is `variant` another entity with a relation ManyTo on `product` ?

Comment: here you go: http://pastebin.com/nPuDDmPD and yes, variant is a onetomany relation

Comment: I edited. Just try it but I have a big doubt on the request. I think you've to do a sub request on variant to get the good sum

Comment: actually this can't work out, cause getCurrentStock() is also a function. see pastebin :/

Comment: @Tronic this answer is correct. You cannot use a function/method directly inside your query instead you have to define the logic into a query constraint as Julien suggested in his answer.

Comment: Ok I will totally delete and recreate my answer.

Comment: Done. As I explained in my new answer : you can't do it better in your application. You have to pass by a symfony external way

Answer (score 1):

A different approach to solve your problem:

```
//In your controller

$bestsellers = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('CoreBundle:Products')->findAll();

$results = [];

foreach ($bestsellers as $bestseller) {
    if ($bestseller->getStockSoldPercentage() >= '75') {
        $results[] = $bestseller;
    }
} 

return $this->render('YourTemplate.html.twig', ["results" = > $results]);
```

Comment: i thought about this as well, but isn't querying all besteller objects and generating a new array based on a filter also too overkill regarding memory? this way i have to query like 2000 objects for just adding like 10 to a special array… what do you think?

Comment: I agree, this is not the "cleanest" option. However, 2K rows should not have a real performance impact. Anyway, the best approach is what Julien has described.

Answer (score 0):

This is actually classic example of why many applications will have two databases.  One is for real time updates and the second is for reporting.

Consider calculating the new stock sold percentage each time a stock is sold and then storing the value someplace.  This would obviously slow down your individual stock transaction but speed your reporting queries up considerably.  Deciding if that is an acceptable trade off is up to you.

Eventually you could move to a more event based system in which selling a stock would trigger a message.  A completely independent process would listen for these messages and update your reporting tables accordingly.  Which would give the best of both worlds.

Comment: Well this isn't about reporting. We need this percentage value live on out production website to calculate some stuff...

Comment: It's the same concept.  In this case the report is an html document instead of a piece of paper.  Maybe take a look at the CSQ pattern: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation